# How to insert a div between two divs?

Tags: html, insert, between

I have two small divs at the two left and right corners of my page. There is a lot of space between them. I want to occupy all that space with another div.

Here is the CSS code:

```
.signatureBox{
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 65px;
    padding: 3px;
    display: block;'
}
```

and the HTML code:

```
<div class='signatureContainer'>
     <span class='signatureBox' style='float: left;' >
            <span>employee</span>
            <hr style='margin-top: 70px;' />
            <span>Role</span>
     </span>
    <span class='signatureBox' style='float: left'>
            <span>employee</span>
            <hr style='margin-top: 70px;' />
            <span>Role</span>
    </span>
    <span class='signatureBox' style='float: right'>
            <span> &nbsp; </span>
            <hr style='margin-top: 70px;' />
            <span> Master &nbsp; </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Only one div is visible here in your code. Where is the second one?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to remove the space between them, you should simply set float to left on every one of them.

```
<div class='signatureContainer'>
 <span class='signatureBox' style='float: left;' >
        <span>employee</span>
        <hr style='margin-top: 70px;' />
        <span>Role</span>
 </span>
<span class='signatureBox' style='float: left'>
        <span>employee</span>
        <hr style='margin-top: 70px;' />
        <span>Role</span>
</span>
<span class='signatureBox' style='float: left'>
        <span> &nbsp; </span>
        <hr style='margin-top: 70px;' />
        <span> Master &nbsp; </span>
</span>
```